# How can i sign in to instagram using php so i can web scrape an instragram url?

Tags: php, instagram

I want to web scrape an instagram url so I can obtain the user thats making the post. I know that first to web scrape that url i need to sign in to instagram but the question is that i dont know how to sign in.

```
$data = array(
    "username" => "*******",
    "password" => "******"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: What *does* happen/echo? Any errors? Are you checking for them? What is the question/problem?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: Use correct upper case letters (in your title). And ask instagram.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is against Instagram's terms and conditions:

https://help.instagram.com/1188470931252371

> 8. We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any
>      content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited
>      to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard
>      search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with
>      Instagram's express consent).